# Mapping series of points in CSV file

Tags: csv, time-series, altitude, path

I've got a CSV file with bird-tracking data in. Each bird has its own unique ID, and has 1 or more unique flight IDs. Each flight ID has several timestamped lat/long points (digital degrees) and it's these I want to visually represent. There is also an altitude value for each point.

I'd like to find out the best program & method to plot these on a map. I'm envisaging an end product similar to my profile picture - Any ideas?

Comment: There are a whole host of options for mapping spatial data. You should probably think more about your specific requirements, else your question will likely be closed for [needing more focus, or for generating opinion-based answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). What do you want from your end map? For example, should it be static/interactive, will it be a webmap/image/pdf, do you have access to any particular software?

Comment: What GIS software do you have access to?

Comment: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/animating_time_series.html